# Exclude certain files, by name, while looping through files in a folder

Tags: excel, vba

The below code loops through files in a folder and adds the file names to a range in Excel.

```
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

Dim DNDsh As Worksheet
Dim wb As Workbook

'On Error GoTo ErrHandlr

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder("H:\Desktop\FILES")

Set wb = Workbooks("DOC.xlsm")

Set DNDsh = wb.Worksheets("DO NOT DELETE")

DNDsh.Range("A:A").ClearContents

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    DNDsh.Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name
    i = i + 1
Next oFile
```

I am looking to exclude files that contain "POSITION" in the name.

I tried with InStr, but this doesn't work.

```
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If InStr(oFile.Name, "Position") < 0 Then
        DNDsh.Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next oFile
```

Comment: Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/instr-function) for what `InStr` returns if the text is not found. Hint: it's not less than 0.

Comment: So in this case it should be If InStr(___) =0? I tested this and it doesn't seem to work. @BigBen

Comment: Should be `=0`. Under the **Return Values** section, if  `string2 is not found`, the result is `0`.

Comment: Sorry yes I did read it. I tried =0, but it is returning all of the values. Am I using "oFile.Name" correctly?

Comment: Maybe `Debug.Print InStr(oFile.Name, "Position")` to see what `InStr` is actually returning.

Comment: Found the solution - was supposed to use oFile, not oFile.Name. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Had to use oFile instead of oFile.Name. Also found that the Instr string is case sensitive, so I fixed to uppercase.

```
For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If InStr(oFile, "POSITION") = 0 Then
        DNDsh.Cells(i + 1, 1) = oFile.Name
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next oFile
```